# What are the dis-advantages of installing the ssl certificate for the naked domain?

Tags: web-hosting, https

I might buy an SSL certificate for my sie.  I know that it will help me in many ways.  But will there be dis-advantages also?

eg.

  If I load an image from another server (using plain http), will that alert the customer saying something is wrong?

  Will I be able to use all existing codes like phpbb, awstats etc without a problem?

  Will there be any issue if redirect a page from my **example.com** to my **subdomain.example.com** using a meta refresh or .htaccess?

  Will there be any issue if redirect a page from my **subdomain.example.com** to my  **example.com** using a meta refresh or .htaccess?

 Any other issue that I might get into?

Thanks.

Comment: Definitely loading content from http sources (instead of https) will generate warnings as it is a security weakness. Consider using SSL only when necessary (exchanging sensitive information) as it slows down the connection.

Comment: @milo5b: A 2% network overhead isn't considered by most to be very significant. The truth is, the performance penalty of SSL is largely moot at this point, that's why companies like Google have begun switching to all-SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Using relative links (which in ssl is therefore ssl) is one method. Omitting the protocol from links is another, so your links would be:

```
//other-website.com
```

I use protocol relative links in my (personal/business) site just for that reason. I hope to convert it to all ssl before too long and why worry about it if it works?

Look into the SPDY protocol and also http(s) headers for caching your content or you might get into problems with site speed.

Answer (score 0):

You will absolutely run into issues if you are loading content outside of your secured URL. If it's from larger sources - such as loading jQuery from the Google servers, most of them have SSL so you can include that securely. Otherwise it's best not to have the entire site secured if you are going to include external content. Just secure the pages where sensitive information is being transmitted and don't include any external content on those pages.

If you are still running into trouble with unsecured content warnings, I highly recommend using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) as a debugging tool to help you find the content that's not coming in secure.

If you will be using subdomains that need secure, you should consider a wildcard SSL certificate, which secures all subdomains of a single domain. They're a bit more expensive, but worth the price if you're going to be securing several subdomains.